# Why does my navigation div not extend to the full width of the screen on mobile devices?

Tags: css

I need some troubleshooting help from some CSS experts. :)

My website at www.daylightfoods.com loads perfectly on full desktop browsers. While the home page on mobile devices works as well, the sub pages on mobile devices have a problem with the navigation div at the top. I am finding that the navigation div (where the grey background is and the navigation links) is not expanding to the full width of the mobile device screen. I can't figure out why, and would love some help!

I have been doing my mobile testing Google Chrome for iOS (both iPhone 5S and iPad).

Here is the page in question:
http://www.daylightfoods.com/sustainability/

It loads perfectly well on desktop versions, but on mobile devices the navigation at the top for some reason is not full 100% width.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have all necessary prefixes like `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc.?

Comment: Do you host it though a hosting service or from your computer?

Comment: @Progo - It's hosted on a professional live web server. What prefixes would be necessary for making the div full width on a mobile screen? I have just been trying the "width:100%;" css code thinking it would make it expand to the full width.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is caused by `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` on your subpages

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This did the trick. You sir, are a scholar and a gentleman. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Check if, inside the div, you have any hidden elements for which you have not set "width: 100%".

In my case I had an hidden `img` (set to only show up only on large screens) that didn't have a "width: 100%" attribute and thus, even when not visible, the image was extending outside of the parent container (the div), preventing the parent container to take all available screen space.

Hope it helps.