# Why does DIV not occupy entire width of screen on mobile Chrome when another DIV has 100% width?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

Here is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.a {
    background: orange;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.b {
    padding: 0 2em;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a">Foo</div>
<div class="b">Bar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output I see when I view the page with an Android mobile device with Chrome browser.

[image]

The issue here is that the orange `div` does not cover the whole width of the page.

My question is not how to fix it. I know how to fix it. If I remove `width: 100%` from `.b`, it fixes this issue.

My question is about why this issue occurs only with Chrome on a mobile device but not on any other browser or not on Chrome on Desktop?

The related question at [Why does my navigation div not extend to the full width of the screen on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21591662/1175080) does not answer my question because none of the answer there discusses the CSS or user agent rules that causes this issue. More importantly I am trying to understand why this issue occurs only on Chrome on a mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue does indeed occur on Chrome on desktop, and is not restricted to just mobiles.

As for the cause of your problem, it's to do with the **[`box model`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing)**:

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This means that when you set width and height you have to adjust the value you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.

In order to ensure that your `.b` element is constrained within the width of the container is to apply **[`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing)** it, as is seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.a {
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.b {
  padding: 0 2em;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="a">Foo</div>
  <div class="b">Bar</div>
</body>
```

`box-sizing: border-box` tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will **include** any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.